# Can't connect to another user than root through SSH

Tags: ssh, sshd, key-authentication

I'm trying to connect to a server on my local network using SSH and would like to be able to login as `storm` but not as `root` (for obvious security purposes). I copied my .pub key to the `.ssh/authorized_keys`

With this /etc/ssh/sshd_config :

```
PermitRootLogin no
[...]
Match Address 192.168.1.*,127.0.0.1
   PermitRootLogin yes
```

I get :

```
$ ssh root@ip
Enter passphrase for key 'PATH_OF_THE_KEY'
$ ssh storm@ip
Permission denied (publickey).
```

---

With this new line at the end :

`AllowUsers storm` or `AllowUsers storm root`

I get :

```
$ ssh root@ip
Permission denied (publickey).
$ ssh storm@ip
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Even with the `Match Address` block commented, it blocks me both root & user.
Can someone help me ?

---

EDIT :
Log for each failed connection with storm user

```
localhost sshd[698]: Invalid user storm from 192.168.1.11
localhost sshd[443]: input_userauth_request: invalid user storm [preauth]
localhost sshd[698]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.11 [preauth]
```

No passwords allowed :

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

`ssh -v root@ip` and `ssh -v storm@ip` give the same output with `AllowUsers storm`:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.33 [192.168.1.33] port XXXX.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/storm/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/storm/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/storm/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/storm/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/storm/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 3
debug1: identity file /home/storm/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/storm/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/storm/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
debug1: Host '[192.168.1.33]:XXXX' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/storm/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/storm/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/storm/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Offering ECDSA public key: /home/storm/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/storm/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

EDIT2 :

```
drwx------  2 root root 4096 19 sept. 15:47 .ssh
-r-------- 1 root root  236 19 sept. 15:47 authorized_keys
```

EDIT3 :

Now working ! Thanks to Brandon Xavier.
I didn't understood that each user (server side) needs to have his own .ssh directory, which is undoubtedly logic after-thought.

---

But now i'm able to login as storm (which is what I wanted) but not anymore as direct root.

Both `root` & `storm` have their .ssh directory, `authorized_keys` files, with correct owners/permissions and the same public key for each `authorized_keys` file. SSHD config file is always with the `Match` block.
What could block root access ?

Comment: Look at `auth.log` entries, and the also add the output using `ssh -v` to connect.

Comment: "Invalid user storm"? O.o What does `getent passwd storm` return on that server?

Comment: storm:x:1000:1000::/home/storm:/bin/bash

Comment: Check the permissions on your `.ssh` directory and `authorized_keys` file

Comment: @brandon-xavier Added. Does the user storm (server side) need to be able to access to the directory or authorized_keys file ?

Comment: `.ssh` and everything under it should be owned by the user (in this case 'storm') and only the user should have permission.  `chown -R storm ~storm/.ssh; chmod 700 ~storm/.ssh;chmod 600 ~storm/.ssh/authorized_keys` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @BrandonXavier ! I don't know which stupidity i've done after that, but now direct root access doesn't work anymore :( I just created .ssh for storm, set the permissions, copied the authorized_keys from root to storm .ssh, and set storm ownership on it. Finally, how can i accept your comment as most helpful answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.ssh` and everything under it should be owned by the user (in this case 'storm') and only the user should have permission. `chown -R storm ~storm/.ssh; chmod 700 ~storm/.ssh;chmod 600 ~storm/.ssh/authorized_keys` should do the trick.

**If** you have control over who's able to log into the console, you can get away without the `Match` block and the `AllowUsers` directive by simply disabling passwords and allowing root login only with a key:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

Be sure to test this while you have access to the console . . . just in case.

Answer (score 2):

What about "PaswordAuthentication" in your config file? if you have modified your config remember restart the service

some links: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Limit_access_to_openssh_features_with_the_Match_keyword.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. After check `/etc/passwd` I see myuser shell config set to `/bin:false`

```
$ cat /etc/passwd
myuser:x:112:116::/media/sys:/bin/false
```

I have to correct this with `usermod myuser -s /bin/bash` and after that I have :

```
$ cat /etc/passwd
myuser:x:112:116::/media/sys:/bin/bash
```

Voila, it's working well now :)